# Multiple Data Parsings To Add Into Observable Collection

Tags: c#, regex

I am attempting to break down a string of info that looks something like this

```
00:02:38: Message
00:02:39: Message
00:02:41: Message
...
```

using regex so I can populate it to an observable collection. I have the following code which i can parse out each time and message per line

```
Regex timeMatch = new Regex("([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})");
Regex msgMatch = new Regex("([A-Z])(.*)");

foreach (Match msgItem in msgMatch.Matches(logMessges)) {
    Debug.WriteLine(msgItem.Value);
}
foreach(Match timeItem in timeMatch.Matches(logMessges)) {
    Debug.WriteLine(timeItem.Value);
}
```

Which outputs the following into Debug output which is what I want

```
00:02:38
00:02:39
00:02:41

Message
Message
Message
```

What would be the best approach to get those values into a new ObservableCollection which I have already created using the following class

```
public class CallLog {
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

ObservableCollection<CallLog> log = new ObservableCollection<CallLog>();
log.Add(new CallLog {Time = timeItem.Value, Message = msgItem.Value};
```

Using the following getting weird behavior

```
Regex pattern = new Regex("([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})|([A-Z].*)");
foreach (Match m in pattern.Matches(logMessges)) {
    log.Add(new CallLog { Time = m.Groups[1].Value, Message = m.Groups[2].Value });
}

Results:

Time         Message
--------------------
00:02:38
             Message
00:02:39
             Message
00:02:41
             Message
```

Expected behavior is to have it line up

```
Time        Message
-------------------
00:02:39    Message
....
```

Comment: why don't you do one regex for both?

Comment: I attempted that trying a MatchCollection but never got any results

Comment: Using `Add()` is a great idea. And you did it already. Congratulations, problem solved.

Comment: In your "weird behavior" code, you have a `|` between the time and message parts of your regex. That's why it's putting each group in a separate match. Replacing the `|` with `: `, as in my answer, or `:\s+`, as in sln's, will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do it using Capture Collections.
Gets all the matches at once.
This requires all the messages to be in sequence.

Though, I don't know if this is any faster (or different) than stepping
through a find next loop.

```
 # @"(?m)(?:^(?<TimeStamp>[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}):\s+(?<Message>.*)\s*)+"

 (?m)
 (?:
      ^ 
      (?<TimeStamp>                 # (1 start)
           [0-9]{2} : 
           [0-9]{2} : 
           [0-9]{2} 
      )                             # (1 end)
      : \s+ 
      (?<Message> .* )              # (2)
      \s* 
 )+
```

C#:

```
string log = @"
00:02:38: Message1
00:02:39: Message2
00:02:41: Message3
";
Regex RxLog = new Regex(@"(?m)(?:^(?<TimeStamp>[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}):\s+(?<Message>.*)\s*)+");

Match logMatch = RxLog.Match( log );
if ( logMatch.Success )
{
    CaptureCollection ccTS = logMatch.Groups["TimeStamp"].Captures;
    CaptureCollection ccMSG = logMatch.Groups["Message"].Captures;
    for (int i = 0; i < ccTS.Count; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] = {1}  {2}", i, ccTS[i].Value, ccMSG[i].Value);
}
```

Output:

```
 [0] = 00:02:38  Message1
 [1] = 00:02:39  Message2
 [2] = 00:02:41  Message3
```

Comment: thanks for the example is exactly what I was trying to do

Comment: Okay, wasn't sure. Good day!

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex regex = new Regex("([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}): ([A-Z].*)");
ObservableCollection<CallLog> log = new ObservableCollection<CallLog>();

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(logMessges)) {
    log.Add(new CallLog {Time = match.Groups[1].Value, Message = match.Groups[2].Value});
}
```

Everything between a regular pair of parentheses in a regular expression is captured and stored as a group in the match. Thus the whatever the expression `[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}` matches is stored in group one, and `[A-Z].*` in group two. After matching the regular expression, we can pull out these captures from `Match.Groups`.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party here...but I would simply bring the two matching processes into one via the use of named match Capture groups.

Once the mathes (one per each line) are acquired, one can then project them (*Linq speak for `Select`*) into `CallLog` entities. From there one can `Aggregate` each of them into an observable collection.

> Data setup

```
var text = @"00:02:38: Alpha Sentance
00:02:39: Beta
00:02:41: Omega";
```

> Pattern To Capture Both Sets of Data

```
var pattern = @"^(?<Time>[^\s]+)\s(?<Message>[^\r\n]+)";
```

The following code returns an `ObservableCollection<CallLog>`

```
Regex.Matches(text, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select (mt => new CallLog()
                    {
                        Time    = mt.Groups["Time"].Value,
                        Message = mt.Groups["Message"].Value
                    })
     .Aggregate(new ObservableCollection<CallLog>(),
                (collection, log) => { collection.Add(log); return collection;} )
```

> Result

[image]